# Vertical expandable menu activated by a button/icon

Tags: css, maps, navbar

I'm kinda new to bootstrap and i'm trying to make a [left menu like this.](https://mol.org/species/map/Socratea_exorrhiza)

I need to press a button and have the menu expand and the div of the map adjust it's width

```css
#sidebar {
  background-color: #16a085;
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 50px;
  z-index: 2;
}
#sidebar .link-text {
  visibility: hidden;
}
#sidebar:hover .link-text {
  visibility: visible;
}
#sidebar:hover {
  width: 200px;
}
#sidebar a {
  color: white;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#sidebar-nav {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-top: 75px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Sidebar -->
<div id="sidebar" role="navigation">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-
  target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>

  <div id="sidebar-nav">
    <ul class="nav nav-stacked">
      <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>Link1</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></span>Link2</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span>Link3</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>Link4</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span>Link5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- Sidebar End -->
</div>
```

I've tried this so far but i dont know how to hide the menu and put a button/icon to bind the action to expand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the approaches to toggle the sidebar using a button could be to add/remove a CSS class on it. I have named the class `expanded` and its CSS should be as below - which means having the class `expanded` is equivalent to the act of hovering it.

```
#sidebar:hover,
#sidebar.expanded{
  width: 200px;
}
```

Next, you can add a click event listener on the button that adds the `expanded` class on the sidebar, if it is not already there, otherwise removes it. Something like this:

```
if(sidebar.classList.contains("expanded")) {
    sidebar.classList.remove('expanded'); 
} else {
    sidebar.classList.add('expanded');
}
```

```js
var toggleButton = document.getElementById('toggleButton');
toggleButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');
  
  if(sidebar.classList.contains("expanded")) {
    sidebar.classList.remove('expanded'); 
  } else {
    sidebar.classList.add('expanded');
  }
});
```

```css
#sidebar {
  background-color: #16a085;
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 50px;
  z-index: 2;
}
#sidebar .link-text {
  visibility: hidden;
}
#sidebar:hover .link-text {
  visibility: visible;
}
#sidebar:hover,
#sidebar.expanded{
  width: 200px;
}
#sidebar a {
  color: white;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#sidebar-nav {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-top: 75px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Sidebar -->
<div id="sidebar" role="navigation">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-
  target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span id="toggleButton" class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>

  <div id="sidebar-nav">
    <ul class="nav nav-stacked">
      <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>Link1</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></span>Link2</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span>Link3</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>Link4</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span>Link5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- Sidebar End -->
</div>
```